# Can bitcoind and btcd share a datadir?

Tags: blockchain, bitcoind, full-node, datadir, btcd

I've already fully synced the blockchain with btcd, can I point bitcoind at the same `datadir` and use its contents?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, they’re completely incompatible.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use the same `datadir`, but you can tell `btcd` to connect to your locally-running `bitcoind` instance in order to do the initial blockchain sync. This means that you'll end up with two copies of the blockchain (one for `bitcoind` and one for `btcd`) but the sync will happen much faster than starting `btcd` with default settings.

In your `btcd.conf` file:

```
; only connect to locally-running node
connect=127.0.0.1

; no need to query for other nodes
nodnsseed=1

; listen on a port other than the default (if bitcoind is already running on the default)
listen=127.0.0.1:8336

; secure the RPC API so that you can interface with your sycing node by using btcctl
rpcuser=<rpcusername>
rpcpassword=<rpcuserpassword>

; sync with indexes enabled
txindex=1
addrindex=1
```

Now start `btcd`. It should start, but no peers will be connected - you can verify this by running `btcctl getpeerinfo` and you'll get `[]`.

With `btcd` running, force your `bitcoind` node to connect to it by using the command `bitcoin-cli --rpcuser=<bitcoindrpcusername> --rpcpassword=<bitcoindrpcuserpassword> addnode 127.0.0.1:8336 'onetry'`

Now run `btcctl getpeerinfo` again, and you should see that your local `bitcoind` node is connected. `btcd` has started to sync and it should only take a few hours to sync from the local node. This is much faster than the days it would take to sync over the internet.